# Create inverse logical array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a logical array, isLand, that is true if the index is over land and false if the index is not over land, like the ocean. How can I easily create another logical array, isOcean, which is the inverse of isLand. All the ones in isLand will be zeros in isOcean and vice versa.

I know I can do this using a for loop but I feel there is a much better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the logical [NOT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) operator:

```
isOcean = ~isLand;
```

Easy-peasy lemon squeezy! ;)

Comment: Great answer, I was going to use the `find` function that this is much better

Answer (score 4):

As gnovice tells you, ~ (the not operator) is the right answer of course, but you can also use

```
isOcean = isLand == 0;
```

This should work too:

```
isOcean = xor(1,isLand);
```

There are always several ways to solve any problem in MATLAB.